# How to get a French “Passeport Talent” or “French Tech Visa” for employees of an innovative startup?

Tags: visa, france

I was overjoyed to accept a job from a start up in France. However my joy seems to have been short-lived as I began to work on the visa process. My company is eligible for the tech visa, but does not want to hire an immigration consultant, leaving me to figure out the labyrinth of french immigration. The lack of information is incredibly frustrating and the embassies don't respond. If anyone has gone through the the same visa route, I will be very very grateful if you can take me through the process, and list out the documents you have submitted for the same. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you consult https://lafrenchtech.com/en/how-france-helps-startups/french-tech-visa/visa-for-employees/ ? Are there points that are not clear to you ?

Comment: Hello audionuma, indeed I did consult the website. However they donot markout the documents I will need to submit, and I think this is quite imperative for the visa.

Comment: I made this tutorial a while back : https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15882/how-to-get-a-french-passeport-talent-or-french-tech-visa-for-startup-founder